# How to record a simulation video in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to record a video of my model's simulation in NetLogo using the vid extension.
I started recording at the beginning of the simulation and asked to record each view update.
However, my video is only 1 second (1 tick).
Because I asked to save the file in the end.
How do I record 200 ticks of simulation?

```
extensions [ vid bitmap ]



      to setup
      clear-all
      ask patches [
    set pcolor black
      ]
        ask patch 0 0[set pstatus 10 set pcolor 5 set homeX pxcor set homeY pycor]
    create-turtles 10 [
     set breed ricos
     setxy random-ycor random-xcor
     decrease-value
     decrease-price
      ]

 set view-mode "pstatus"
  reset-ticks
end
to go

  vid:start-recorder
    locate-ricos

    ask infras [
    if counter > residents-per-infra
    [locate-infras
      evaluate-infra
      set counter 0]
    ]

  if count (ricos) >= 100 [kill-ricos]
  if count (medias) >= 80 [kill-medias]
  if count (pobres) >= 20 [kill-pobres]


  update-patch-color
  vid:record-view
  tick
  vid:save-recording "filme.mp4"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
extensions [ vid bitmap ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 10
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if vid:recorder-status = "inactive" [
    vid:start-recorder
  ]
  vid:record-view
  ask turtles [ 
    rt random 50 - 25
    fd 1
  ]
  tick
  if ticks = 200 [
    vid:save-recording "filme.mp4" 
    print vid:recorder-status   
    stop
  ]
end
```

The key is that you need to only call `vid:save-recording` when you meet some condition, otherwise it'll get called, report out the one frame, and get reset every single tick.

Comment: I tried what you suggested.
Did not work.
Still recording a 1 second video.

Comment: Did you try a new file with my code only? It works for me. You would have to adapt it to fit your code. Also, can you show your `setup` chunk?

Comment: I did tried a new file with your code only, but It appears an error 
"Netlogo is unable to supply you with more details about this error.."

Comment: @AgnesdeAraujo - Can you just edit that into your question? What version of Netlogo are you using? Also, you may want to check out the asking guidelines, and especially the [MCVE guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on providing reproducible code- anything not included (eg `locate-ricos`, `locate-medias`, `locate-pobres`, etc) will not immediately work for other users. In general, you want to cut any code that is not directly related to the issue you're having.

Comment: Sorry! I edited my question, I added setup chunk. I'm using NetLogo 6.0. But even when  I tried to reproduce your code, I got an error.

Comment: Interesting. I just tried this in Netlogo 6.0 on a new machine and it worked. I did have to save the file though- running it in an unsaved file threw that same error you mentioned.

Comment: Were you able to record the entire simulation? I tried here again and I was able to record the video. But it recorded 1 tick only (tick = 200).

Comment: Yes, the code example I gave (copied and pasted) recorded the entire 200 ticks on two different computers.